# angular + spring boot + nginx

Tags: nginx, spring-boot, angular

Пытаюсь настроить на удаленной машине angular на фронте и spring boot в качестве бэкенд сервера.

Конфиг нгинкса следующий

```
root /var/www/[appdir];

location / {
    root /var/www/[appdir];
    index index.htnl index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

в руте сбилдженные файлы ангулара. при обращении на хост стартовая страница запускается. Далее при попытке авторизации по логике вещей должно идти перенаправление на 8080 порт на котором запущен jar-ник с бэкендом. Но этого почему-то не происходит. Но запросы уходят на мою локальную машину. То есть бэк-сервер, который на моем компе обрабатывает запросы фронта. В proxy_pass вместо localhost пробовал прописать доменное имя, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: 1. Вы точно уверены что фронт обращается к вам на локальный компьютер? У вас белый IP? 2. Не захардкожен ли адрес где-то в ангуляре?

Comment: 3) http://localhost:8080/api/aunthenticate - ангуляр в сервисе обращается по такому запросу.
2) про ip не знаю. На локальном компе ли на удаленном сервере?
1) ну если я перехожу по доменному имени хоста и уменя запущен джарник на моей локальной машине, то с запосом прилетают сущности. И в консоли логи отображаются(на локальной машине).

Answer (score 0):

ну в общем почему-то сработало просто захардкодить в запросах ангулара доменное имя вместо локалхоста. Не совсем, конечно, понял почему так, ну да ладно.